# ng-click if true append a class using ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scenario which is same as toggle where i m appending the class col-xs-6 and dividing the page in two views.
Here when i first click i m passing a variable value as true and in ng-class i am checking for a condition if its true then i am appending col-xs-6 class

Here is my html code which i have tried

```
<div ng-class="{'col-xs-6': isClick}">
<div class="panel panel-default panel-height" ng-repeat="candidateInfo in aCandidateDetails track by $index">
    <div class="panel-heading header-background">
        <div stop-watch time="xyz" name="candidateInfo.name" time-of-interview="candidateInfo.doi" class="stop-watch"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2"><a style="cursor:pointer" class="pull-right">{{candidateInfo.name}}</a></div>
            <div class="col-xs-offset-9"><a style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="isClick=!isClick" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="{{'#'+toggle}}">{{candidateInfo.name}} resume</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div id="{{toggle}}" class="collapse" ng-class="{'col-xs-6': isClick}">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

I have no idea where i am going wrong

Any sort of help is appreciated.

Comment: whats your controller code?

Answer (score 0):

@Piyush.kapoor ,Here is my controller code

```
angular.module('hrPortalApp')
.controller('candidateInterviewCtrl', function($scope, $state, iterateArray, getCandidateInterviewListService) {
    getCandidateInterviewListService.fnGetCandidateDetails(localStorage.getItem('username')).then(function(response) {
        $scope.aCandidateDetails = response;

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it via below code

```
<input id="setbtn" type="button" value="set" ng-click="myVar='my-class'">
<input id="clearbtn" type="button" value="clear" ng-click="myVar=''">
<span class="base-class" ng-class="myVar">Sample Text</span>
```

In above code on first time click you have to set myvar as 'col-xs-6' and in toggle you have to cleat it.

Comment: doesn't made any effect.
Its not working @Nikhil.Patel